# How to input 2dimensional array using pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
void get(int r,int c,int *ptr){
  int i,j,k;
  
  cout<<"Enter Elements of a matrix:"<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<r;j++){
      cin>>k;
      *(ptr + (i*c) + j)=k;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code.

```
*(ptr + (i*c) + j)=k;
```

Can anyone explain how the above line of code works?

Comment: Recommendation: Try to learn from code that follows a responsible naming convention. The code you've shown probably doesn't even work thanks to the two `for` loops iterating the same range. if `r` != `c`, the function either runs off the end or doesn't fill enough of the array.

Comment: The trick being used is a 2D -> 1D mapping function. `i` is the row. Every `i` is multiplied by the number of columns in the row and then the location in the row is added on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is an address in memory where some piece of information is stored. This address takes the form of a number. How many bits that number uses is platform-dependent.

Since that address is a number, we can do math with it.

```cpp
*(ptr + (i*c) + j)=k;
```

Can be the following when we understand operator precedence and use whitespace.

```cpp
*(ptr + i * c + j) = k;
```

We're adding the product of `i` and `c`; and then `j` to the pointer. Then we're dereferencing that whole thing and copying rhe value of `k` into it.

How this relates to arrays is that the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```cpp
arr[1] = 456;

*(arr + 1) = 456;
```

If you're dealing with a multi-dimensional array as a single block of memory, you need to multiply the column width by the number of rows down, and then add however many columns over your data is.

**Perhaps a visual will help.**

Let's consider a 3x3 2-dimensional array. We'll say we've initialized it 1-9.

```
1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9
```

Now, we can look at this as a 3x3 array, or... we can consider it a single dimensional array with 9 elements.

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

How can we access `5`?

Well, in the first case we would use something like: `arr[1][1]`. In the second case, we know that `5` is at index 4, so how do we turn `[1][1]` into `[4]`?

Given the pattern `arr[row][col]` we can multiply the `row` by the length of each row, and then add the `col`. So `arr2d[1][1]` turns into `arr1d[1 * 3 + 1]`. Lo and behold, `1 + 3 + 1` is `4`.

Try this with a bigger array:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

To get the value `18` we would access: `arr2d[3][2]` but if this were treated as a single dimensional array: `arr1d[3 * 5 + 2]` which is `arr1d[17]` which gets us... `18`.

Comment: Can you give more explanation...

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Recommendation: start all the numbering in the examples at 0 so you get a 1:1 mapping between the value in the array and the offset in the array. Should make the examples a bit clearer.

Comment: I thought of that but actually felt it would be confusing.